# When i run npm run dev my next js app Compiling into a path that doesn't exist

Tags: next.js

i create next js app with npx create-next-app@latest and when i run it with npm run dev it open in localhost/login page and it doesn't exist. when i try to manually change path on browser it suddenly reddrect in to localhost/login

here is a pic of termanel
[image]

and my file system
[image]

this is a brand new project i just build it happen in everytime i build a one

i use windows 11 and fire fox as browser

thanks for any help